# Azure policy assigning multiple tags

Tags: json, azure, tags, policy

I'm trying to create a Azure policy to enforce multiple tags on resources.
The requirement is to add tags with a default value and if there exists a tag with same name but different value, ignore that and add the rest of the mandatory tags.
Mandatory tags:
app: tbd (default value)
app_owner: tbd (default value)

Say resource A has tag app: ABC, the policy should not change the app value to tbd but ignore it and add the other tags app_owner: tbd

Issue:
Below code is updating the blank resources with required tags, but if tag already exists, it is not updating the second tag.

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false."
          },
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false"
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4a9ae827-6dc8-4573-8ac7-8239d42aa03f"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "value": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
          },
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
            "value": "[parameters('tagValue2')]"
          }
       ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "app",
        "description": "requires the tag named as 'app' to tag resources"
      }
    },
    "tagValue": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "tbd",
        "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'app'"
      }
    },
    "tagName2": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "app_owner",
        "description": "requires the tag named as 'app_owner' to tag resources"
      }
    },
    "tagValue": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "tbd",
        "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'app_owner'"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to the following policy definition:

```json
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false"
          },
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4a9ae827-6dc8-4573-8ac7-8239d42aa03f"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "value": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
          },
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
            "value": "[parameters('tagValue2')]"
          }
       ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "app",
        "description": "requires the tag named as 'app' to tag resources"
      }
    },
    "tagValue": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "tbd",
        "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'app'"
      }
    },
    "tagName2": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "app_owner",
        "description": "requires the tag named as 'app_owner' to tag resources"
      }
    },
    "tagValue": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "tbd",
        "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'app_owner'"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't quite see the changes that you are suggesting to make in the policy definition.